# Any Charts available for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to implement charts for my windows phone 8 application, I could not able to find chart control in sdk, Are there any free chart tools available for free in Windows Phone 8.
-Mahens

Comment: +1 could you also mention what type of charts you're looking for?

Comment: Im loking plain bar charts. I think currently there are no chart available , I have to build this bar charts with Borders and Rectangles.

Comment: @user145610 did you find any ? see here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294344/amchart-customization-for-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 4):

following library allows you to create charts easily in Windows Phone, and it's free:

https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation to you; surprised that this was not featured in the Windows Phone SDK.  However, I came to learn that it is available in the Silverlight v5.0 SDK:

If you install Silverlight v5, then in a directory similar to the following: 
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin**

You should be able to find the dll, which you can add to your WP7.1 / WP8 project:
**System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll**

Then import some useful classes from your referenced assembly into your XAML header by way of namespaces

```
xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" 
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

Then finally start using the chart!

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="MyChart" Title="My Chart">
</charting>
```