# AmChart customization for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, amcharts

I have working on Windows Phone 8 app and i am trying to implement Charting library.

I have used the charting example given here :http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/mango-sample-chart-data

Its good, but i am not able to customize it.

3 issues is :

1) Onclick of slice i need to get the value.

2) How to add Double tap ?

3) legends should be at the bottom aligned horizontally.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is my XAML file:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,0,0">
            <charts:PieChart Width="400"
                             Name="pieChart"
                             Height="400"
                             DoubleTap="pieChart_DoubleTap"
                             Tap="PieChart_Tap"
                             ValueMemberPath="Value"
                             TitleMemberPath="title "
                             Background="Black">
                <charts:PieChart.Brushes>
                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0,0" Center="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#73C766" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#73C766" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0,0" Center="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#6668C7" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#6668C7" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0,0" Center="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#C766C7" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#C766C7" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </charts:PieChart.Brushes>
                <charts:PieChart.DataSource>
                    <local:PieDataCollection>
                        <local:PieData title="ABC" Value="100"></local:PieData>
                        <local:PieData title="XYZ" Value="100"></local:PieData>
                        <local:PieData title="PQR" Value="100"></local:PieData>
                    </local:PieDataCollection>
                </charts:PieChart.DataSource>
            </charts:PieChart>
        </Grid>
```

1) I have added both

```
DoubleTap="pieChart_DoubleTap" Tap="PieChart_Tap"
```

But i dont know how can i get the values.

2) I dont know how to alling the legends horzontally

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? I am pretty sure all questions can be answered easily if you know how to work with XAML

Comment: Please see my edit, if you know how please provide me some solution that i can try

Comment: What happens when you tap on the control? Do you know how to handle those events? 2) Do you know how to style controls?

Comment: @ToniPetrina Yes, i am newebie to Windows Phone 8 appp development and seeking for help

Comment: @ToniPetrina Are you there ? you toold me that it can be easily done, can you please show me how ?

Comment: In principle, yes, but I would have to download amCharts, create project etc. Handling Tap and DoubleTap isn't specific to your code, that is universal handling. Just inspect the `sender` and `e.OriginalSource` for the values. Also, customizing the control template is again something that is done for *any* control and can also be applied here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49389/discussion-between-goofy-and-toni-petrina)

Comment: @Goofy did you find any solution? Can you please share you findings, It will be really appropriated if you share. I am also facing some legend issue in Pie Chart.

Comment: @gofor.net IN WP8 they have there own Chart `Data Visualization` just check for that its good